# pandas - Apply different groupby functions to a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am coming to pandas from a SQL background, where I would have used a PARTITION BY function to aggregate two columns to a different level.

Here is the dataframe

```
 TeamName   PlayerID    PlayerLevel
 A          1           Beginner
 A          2           Beginner
 A          3           Intermediate
 A          4           Intermediate
 A          5           Intermediate
 A          6           Advanced
 B          7           Beginner
 B          8           Beginner
 B          9           Advanced
 B          10          Intermediate
 B          11          Beginner
 B          12          Advanced
```

I want to count the players who fall into each Player Level, which I can do easily using

```
             .groupby(['TeamName', 'PlayerLevel'], as_index=False) \
        .agg({'PlayerID': 'count'})
```

this gets me this

```
 TeamName   PlayerLevel     PlayerID
 A          Beginner        2
 A          Intermediate    3
 A          Advanced        1
 B          Beginner        3
 B          Intermediate    1
 B          Advanced        2
```

but what I also want is the "denominator", so the total number of players for each team. Example data frame (with columns renamed) (the denominator happens to be 6 for both teams in this example).

```
 TeamName   PlayerLevel     Numerator  Denominator
 A          Beginner        2          6
 A          Intermediate    3          6
 A          Advanced        1          6
 B          Beginner        3          6
 B          Intermediate    1          6
 B          Advanced        2          6
```

But I can't figure out how to get multiple grouby aggregations to play nicely together.

Answer (score 2):

Per @root's suggestion and motivated by @Jeff's comments
Which also happens to be equivalent to @MaxU's answer even if it looks slightly different.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['TeamName', 'PlayerLevel']).size().to_frame('Numerator')
df1['Denominator'] = df1.groupby(level='TeamName').transform(sum)

df1
```

[image]

---

#### Old Answer

```
numerator = df.groupby(['TeamName', 'PlayerLevel']).size().rename('numerator')
numerator

TeamName  PlayerLevel 
A         Advanced        1
          Beginner        2
          Intermediate    3
B         Advanced        2
          Beginner        3
          Intermediate    1
Name: numerator, dtype: int64
```

---

```
denominator = df.groupby(['TeamName']).size().rename('denominator')
denominator

TeamName
A    6
B    6
Name: denominator, dtype: int64
```

---

```
numerator.to_frame().merge(denominator.to_frame(),
                           right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

[image]

---

```
df.groupby(['TeamName', 'PlayerLevel']).size().unstack() \
    .div(df.groupby(['TeamName']).size(), axis=0)
```

[image]

---

Comment: try using transform instead of groupby-merge

Comment: so doing it all in one step is not possible? instead, create the two separate data frames and then combine on the keys?

Comment: @Jeff I couldn't figure out how to use it for this problem.

Comment: @piRSquared 2nd effort much LESS idiomatic and more obtuse

Comment: @Jeff agreed. I'll keep thinking

Comment: I think to use `transform`:  Get the numerator using your current `groupby` method (but just call it `df`), then do something like `df['denominator'] = df.groupby('TeamName')['numerator'].transform('sum')`.

Answer (score 1):

This isnt in right form as OP wants, But the question feels like crosstab.
Maybe someone can recast into the form OP wants.

```
dfx = pd.crosstab(df['TeamName'], df['PlayerLevel'], margins =True)
dfx = dfx.drop("All")
dfx

PlayerLevel   Advanced  Beginner  Intermediate  All
TeamName                                          
A                   1         2             3    6
B                   2         3             1    6
```

Answer (score 1):

First create your `numerator`:

```
df = df.groupby(['TeamName','PlayerLevel'], as_index=False).count()
df = df.rename(columns={'PlayerID':'numerator'})

  TeamName   PlayerLevel  numerator
0        A      Advanced          1
1        A      Beginner          2
2        A  Intermediate          3
3        B      Advanced          2
4        B      Beginner          3
5        B  Intermediate          1
```

Then use `transform` to get the sum of the counts one level up against `'TeamName'`. Use `transform` as it naturally broadcasts the aggregation result against the index of each group, thus allow you to assign the result:

```
df['denominator'] = df.groupby('TeamName')['numerator'].transform(sum)

  TeamName   PlayerLevel  numerator  denominator
0        A      Advanced          1            6
1        A      Beginner          2            6
2        A  Intermediate          3            6
3        B      Advanced          2            6
4        B      Beginner          3            6
5        B  Intermediate          1            6
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
In [32]: (df.groupby(['TeamName', 'PlayerLevel'])
   ....:    .size()
   ....:    .to_frame('Numerator')
   ....:    .reset_index()
   ....:    .assign(Denominator=df.groupby('TeamName').PlayerID.transform('count'))
   ....: )
Out[32]:
  TeamName   PlayerLevel  Numerator  Denominator
0        A      Advanced          1            6
1        A      Beginner          2            6
2        A  Intermediate          3            6
3        B      Advanced          2            6
4        B      Beginner          3            6
5        B  Intermediate          1            6
```